# Storing class instances in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a few classes that I'd like to store instances of it in the redux store.

The classes are singletons, and there is only one instance for each class.
And I store them in the state with the name of the class (or something unique) as a key.

I can store them just fine, but component's are not rerendering.

I think it's because I'm always mutating the instance (because it's singleton)

How should I store/use class instance in redux?
What if it's a singletone instance?

- edit

I have plain objects/arrays in the singletone instance.
Ah there's a function (action creator) in it as well.
(which will be executed by redux-thunk)

Actually, if that's problematic, or not a best practice, I guess I could store name of the actionCreator in the store and have name -> actionCreator map somewhere outside of the store.

One of the action creator is below

```
 function datetimeStockExtrasForDateRange(date) {

   return function (dispatch, getState) {

     const state = getState()
     const { calendar } = state
     const calendarPeriod = calendar.calendarPeriod

     let visibleDates = calendarUtil.visibleDates(date, calendarPeriod)

     const filteredDates = visibleDates.filter( (date) => {
       var dateFormatted = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
       if (state.dates[dateFormatted] && state.dates[dateFormatted].available_datetime_stock_extras_fetched) {
         return false
       }
       return true
     })

     if (!_.isEmpty(filteredDates)) {
       const { datetime_stock_rule_set_id } = state.calendar
       const date_start = filteredDates[0]
       const date_end = filteredDates[filteredDates.length - 1]
       dispatch(
         DatetimeStockExtra.fetchAvailableDatetimeStockExtrasForDateRangeAction(
           datetime_stock_rule_set_id,
           date_start,
           date_end
         )
       )
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: do you have code sample?

Comment: What do you have in your singletons?

Comment: @Crysfel I've updated the question

Comment: @TheReason I've updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it's a singleton suggests to me that it's mutable, and that your reducers are modifying it directly instead of projecting new instances of it in response to actions. This is a misuse of redux and will cause react-redux to not recognize changes.